# Prime divisors of a number in ML

Tags: integer, primes, sml, prime-factoring

In ML i want to get the prime divisors of a number. How can I do this, I am beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the simple trial division, this starts with `p=2` and repeatedly divides `n` by `p`, incrementing `p` as it goes.

```
open LargeInt  (* if you want to work with huge numbers like 5000000000 *)
infix 7 quot rem
val prime_factors =
  let fun trial_division p n =
    if p > n then nil else
      if n rem p = 0
        then p :: trial_division  p      (n quot p)
        else      trial_division (p + 1)  n
  in trial_division 2 end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several general algorithms for finding the prime divisors of an integer: see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). [Trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) with a simple primality test is simplest to understand.

Find or devise an algorithm in pseudocode; only then worry about how to put it into ML.